# Troubleshooting populating associative array from awk generated tab delimited file

Tags: bash, associative-array

I have generated a tab delimited file using `samtools` and `awk`. I am attempting to populate an associative array with the tab delimited file. The keys and values of the associative array will then be used in a function for downstream analysis.

When attempting to populate the associative array using the code the file lines are read into `$queryid` and the tab is converted to a space. I have tried running the code with `IFS=\` and `IFS="\t"` in addition to what is shown below.

```
samtools view $1 "NA" | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } ; { print $1, $4 }' > "$3/$1_ReadStarts.txt"

declare -A Readstart
while IFS= read queryid startpos; do
  echo $queryid >> "$3/test.txt"#this line was added for troubleshooting
  Readstart[$queryid]=$startpos
  done < "$3/$1_ReadStarts.txt"
```

A portion of the input file (`ReadStarts.txt`) generated from `samtools` and `awk` is shown below. An portion of `$queryid` (shown in `test.txt`) which should be the keys or the array is shown below. It contains the second column from `ReadStarts.txt` which should be stored in `$startpos`.

> ReadStarts.txt
>   NB501950:166:HVN2GBGXB:3:21607:13181:3898   13397
>   NB501950:166:HVN2GBGXB:3:23607:24238:3455   16224
>   NB501950:166:HVN2GBGXB:3:23402:13620:6968   18402
>
> test.txt
>   NB501950:166:HVN2GBGXB:3:21607:13181:3898 13397
>   NB501950:166:HVN2GBGXB:3:23607:24238:3455 16224
>   NB501950:166:HVN2GBGXB:3:23402:13620:6968 18402

Comment: The code block cut off the last portion of that line. The > "$ should read > "$3/$1_ReadStarts.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your `IFS` settings are correct. `IFS=` is the way to *unset* the variable, not set it equal to a space. In fact, you don't need to set `IFS` at all, since it defaults to spaces, tabs, and newlines.

```sh
declare -A Readstart
while read -r queryid startpos; do
  echo "$queryid"
  echo "$startpos"
  Readstart[$queryid]="$startpos"
done < "stackOverflow.txt"
```

worked for me with the sample file you provided.

---

If you later need to know how to set `IFS`:

- newline: `IFS=$'\n'`
- tab: `IFS=$'\t'`
- space: `IFS=' '`

Comment: Thank you. The script appears to be working after expanding the escape sequence on the tab character.